# Java and Octal numbers

Tags: java, octal

I want a user to input an integer and then convert the number. How do I tell Java that the input integer is base 8? As, I can't append a '0' to the front of an integer variable.

Comment: An `int` is a 32-bit signed number which has no format.  When you create an `int` value, the fact it was once an octal or decimal has been lost.

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer.parseInt("20", 8);
```

will treat the input as octal. In general, the second parameter is the base.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the suggestion. I figured it out. The answer I was looking for lies in the javadoc for the Scanner class.